# PHP PDO SQLServer TrustServerCertificate

Tags: php, sql-server

estoy intentando conectarme desde PHP a un servidor de SQLServer 2008 R2.

No me estoy pudiendo conectar, me tira el error de TrustServerCertificate=false:

Tengo el siguiente código pero no se donde exactamente debo agregar el TrustServerCertificate=false.

he probado con una conexion estandar y me funciona bien usando sqlsrv_connect.

pero en este no logro dar con la talla

```
private function __construct($dbtype, $db_host, $db_name, $db_user, $db_pass) {
        $this->host = $db_host;
        $this->name = $db_name;
        $this->user = $db_user;
        $this->pass = $db_pass;
        $this->type = $dbtype;
        $db_driver = strtolower($this->name) == "lin2db" || strtolower($this->name) == "lin2world" ? "sqlsrv:Server" : "mysql:host";
        $db_database = strtolower($this->name) == "lin2db" || strtolower($this->name) == "lin2world" ? "Database" : "dbname";
        if($this->type == "login"){
            try {
                self::$db_login = new \PDO($db_driver."=".$this->host."; ".$db_database."=".$this->name, $this->user, $this->pass);
                self::$db_login->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                self::$db_login->exec('SET NAMES utf8');
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                return false;
            }
        }elseif($this->type == "game"){
            try {
                self::$db_game = new \PDO($db_driver."=".$this->host."; ".$db_database."=".$this->name, $this->user, $this->pass);
                self::$db_game->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                self::$db_game->exec('SET NAMES utf8');
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ese error lo que te esta diciendo es que tu servidor tiene el certificado en false cuando debe ser true ... eso es configuracion del servidor de base de datos...

Comment: ya probe eso tambien, lo que necesito es poner es TrustServerCertificate=false esto en mi codigo

Comment: eso no va en el codigo eso se configura en el servidor de base de datos.

Comment: $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DbName",
                         "UID"=>"UserName",
                         "PWD"=>"Password",
                         "Encrypt"=>true,
                         "TrustServerCertificate"=>false);

En PHP es un y va aqui... y en el PDO no se donde colocarlo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42188894/17161735

Comment: tienes que usar PDO_ODBC  o PDO_MSSQL

Answer (score 2):

Encript esta en unused estatus para PDO; del sitio en ingles encontre esto: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024351/how-to-create-an-encrypted-connection-to-sql-server-from-ubuntu-using-php-pdo)

---

***Traduccion Literal:***

¿Podría ser que `Encrypt=true;TrustServerCertificate` no se tengan en cuenta en absoluto?
Sin ser un experto en esto, consulte la documentación en `PHP` sobre `PDO` y `DSN`. Como está escrito, hay un parámetro especial en el `DSN` que se llama `secure` y actualmente no se usa. No estoy seguro de si se supone que esta es la forma correcta de declarar que desea una conexión segura en este DSN y tampoco es útil el hecho de que esté etiquetado como `unused`.

Además también haz lo siguiente:

> In php.ini make sure the following is set: mssql.secure_connection =
> On

Eche un vistazo si la conexión a través de `PDO_ODBC` es mejor para lo que desea lograr. Para conectarse a través de `PDO_ODBC`, consulte este [Ejemplo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php#98716).

---

Adicional a eso puedes hecharle un vistaso a [PDO-SQLSRV](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php).

Answer (score 0):

yo solvente esto colocando este string

```
$nombreBaseDeDatos = "nombre-servidor";
$rutaServidor = "servidor";

try {
    $base_de_datos = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$rutaServidor;database=$nombreBaseDeDatos;TrustServerCertificate=true", $usuarioBD, $contrasenaBD);
    $base_de_datos->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Ocurrió un error con la base de datos: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: Hola Wilmar, bienvenido y gracias por tu colaboración, las respuestas que son solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad, te sugiero que edites la tuya, y expliques de que forma resuelve el problema planteado, así evitarás que sea cerrada y/o recibir votos negativos. 
ver [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y obtener una medalla!.